# Adapt jQuery hover sequence to run automatically on loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hover

I adapted this script from codepen.io in order to change a bit of text when user hover over the text. It has a shuffle effect on hover and when you leave the hover zone it settles on one text.

Since the user will use this on mobile, it is quite difficult to replicate the hover effect with touch. I'm thinking to allow the text to cycle through automatically on repeat with a timed delay.

When user lands on "doomsday" it presents a different version of `body` class.

```
var day = [
"monday",
"tuesday",
"wednesday"
],
allDays = day.length,
firstDay = 0,
change = $('.day'),
changeDay = function() {
  change.html(day[firstDay]);
  firstDay = (firstDay + 1) % allDays;
}

function ohNo() {
  ohYeah = setInterval(changeDay, 120);
};

$('.day').hover(function() {
  $('body').removeClass('uhoh');
  $('#link').removeClass('live');
  ohNo();
}, function() {
  clearInterval(ohYeah);
  if ($('.day').text() == 'doomsday') {
    $('body').addClass('uhoh');
    $('#link').addClass('live');

  }
})
```

I've tried to do a `setInterval` on loop however the code has been freezing non-stop, then another `setInterval` after the initial animation is over. However the animation is not lining up properly.

Ideally I would like to like to replicate the effect of hovering for 2 seconds, then pause for 2 seconds, indefinitely. If anyone could point me to the right direction in doing sequential `setInterval` with `jQuery` I'd appreciate it. Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to display each element in `day` array for two seconds, then repeat the process?

Comment: Do you need to use jQuery?  Couldn't you just use a `while (true) {}` loop to call the hover function for 2 seconds then wait 2 seconds?